# Unrecognized slot name v-slot:item in Vuetify v-breadcrumb

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js

I'm using vue3 and vuetify to make a website and I'm trying to understand how to make a breadcrumb menu.

What I'm trying to do is to make the breadcrumb menu look like thick arrows but nowhere in the documentation have I found how... The arrows in the examples don't cover the whole menu and they are way too small. Also I tried to customize the items like in an example I saw but when I hover over "item" in v-slot:item, it says: "Unrecognized slot name" and no changes happen... Can anyone help me please?

So far my code is like this:

```
<template>
<v-breadcrumbs :items="items">
    <template v-slot:item="{ item }">
        <v-breadcrumbs-item slot="item">
            <span :style="'color:green'">{{ item.text.toUpperCase() }} </span>
        </v-breadcrumbs-item>
    </template>
</v-breadcrumbs>
</template>

<script>
export default {
name: "MyVueWebsite",
data: function () {
    return {
        items:[
            {
                title:'crumbmenu 1',
                disabled:false,
                href:'faa'
            },{
                title:'crumbmenu 2',
                disabled:false,
                href:'foo'
            },{
                title:'crumbmenu 3',
                disabled:false,
                href:'fii'
            },

        ]
    }
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this seems to be an error in the Vuetify 3 docs. There is no `item` slot in Vuetify 3 anymore, only a `title` slot, that is passed to each of the `v-breadcrumb-item`:

```html
<v-breadcrumbs :items="items">
  <template v-slot:title="{ item, index }">
    <span :style="{color:'green'}">{{ item.title.toUpperCase() }} </span>
  </template>
</v-breadcrumbs>
```

Use the `divider` slot if you want to use arrows (or something else) between the breadcrumbs:

```html
<v-breadcrumbs :items="items">
  <template v-slot:divider="{ item, index }">
    <v-icon>mdi-arrow-right</v-icon>
  </template>
</v-breadcrumbs>
```

Here it is in a snippet:

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify
const vuetify = createVuetify()

const app = {
  data: function() {
    return {
      items: [{
          title: 'crumbmenu 1',
          disabled: false,
          href: 'faa'
        }, {
          title: 'crumbmenu 2',
          disabled: false,
          href: 'foo'
        }, {
          title: 'crumbmenu 3',
          disabled: false,
          href: 'fii'
        },

      ]
    }
  }

}
createApp(app).use(vuetify).mount('#app')
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.13/dist/vuetify.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-breadcrumbs :items="items">
        <template v-slot:title="{ item, index }">
          <span :style="{color:'green'}">{{ item.title.toUpperCase() }} </span>
        </template>
        <template v-slot:divider="{ item, index }">
          <v-icon>mdi-arrow-right</v-icon>
        </template>
      </v-breadcrumbs>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.13/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
```

---

As to the arrow, a simple solution is to adjust the height of the items and put a triangle into the divider. Have a look at the snippet:

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify
const vuetify = createVuetify()

const app = {
  data: function() {
    return {
      items: [{
          title: 'active item',
          disabled: false,
          active: true,
          href: 'faa'
        }, {
          title: 'disabled item',
          disabled: true,
          href: 'foo'
        }, {
          title: 'regular item',
          disabled: false,
          href: 'fii'
        },

      ]
    }
  }

}
createApp(app).use(vuetify).mount('#app')
```

```css
:root{
  --d-height: 38px;
  --bc-color: cadetblue;
}

.v-breadcrumbs-item{
  height: var(--d-height);
}

.v-breadcrumbs-item.v-breadcrumbs-item--active{
  --bc-color: orange;
  color: white;
}

.arrow-body{
  background: var(--bc-color);
  line-height: var(--d-height);
  padding: 0 8px;
}

.arrow-head{
  --half-height: calc(var(--d-height) / 2);
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: var(--half-height) solid transparent;
  border-bottom: var(--half-height) solid transparent;
  border-left: var(--half-height) solid var(--bc-color);
}

.v-breadcrumbs .v-breadcrumbs-divider{
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3/dist/vuetify.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-breadcrumbs :items="items">
        <template v-slot:title="{ item, index }">
          <div class="arrow-body">{{ item.title.toUpperCase() }} </div><div class="arrow-head"></div>
        </template>
        <template v-slot:divider="{ item, index }"></template>
      </v-breadcrumbs>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
```

You'd have to look at reactivity, and I am not sure in general if this suffices your use case. There are lots of templates for arrow breadcrumbs around the web, if you need a more thorough solution, you are probably better off creating your own component than forcing it on `v-breadcrumbs`.

Comment: Thanks! They really ought to correct their documentation ^^'. Also yes I want to use arrows but not those ones, I want my menu to look like this: https://www.csscodelab.com/responsive-breadcrumb-wrapping-arrow/  do you know how to do it without installing anything other?

Comment: Hmm, I have added a simple solution for the arrows, not sure if it works for you

Comment: It works great! I'll see if I can adjust it so that it looks more like the way it looks in that link but it's already very good. Thanks!

Comment: well now that I'm trying to use the disabled option, if it is set to true then the menu looks weird ^^'. Also could there be a way to mark one of the items as "selected" so that it has another color than the others?

Comment: You can pull the arrow head into the item so that it shares the same style as the arrow body. For selection, there is a class `v-breadcrumbs-item--active` which you can use. Have a look at the updated snippet